# Magento 2: Get order list items for a customer

Tags: magento2, orders, magento2.2

I want to display on a .phtml file a list of order items for a logged in user. I don't want to use object manager.

I can get the id of the logged in user `($customerId)` on the `phtml`.

I have created a block class

```
namespace 'moduleNameSpace';
class Orders extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_customerSession;
    protected $_orderCollectionFactory;
    protected $orders;
    public function __construct(
            \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
            \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
            \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
             array $data = []
        ) {

    $this->_orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;

    parent::__construct($context, $data);
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
}



public function getLoggedinCustomerId() {
    if ($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
        return $this->_customerSession->getId();
    }
    return false;
}


public function getOrders($customerId)
{

    if (!$this->orders) {
        $this->orders = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()->addFieldToSelect(
            '*'
        )->addFieldToFilter(
            'customer_id',
            $customerId
        )->setOrder(
            'created_at',
            'desc'
        );
    }
    return $this->orders;
}
}
```

and then on the .phtml template i have

```
$customerId = $block->getLoggedinCustomerId();
$orders = $block->getOrders($customerId);
foreach ($orders as $order) {
foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item){
   ...
}
}
```

The problem is that `foreach` is not working, even when I want to count the  number of orders for example

```
foreach ($orders as $order) {                                                                 
$orderCount++ ;
}
echo $orderCount;
```

How can I get all order items?
I think the problem may be on the block class

Comment: try this; `if($orders->getSize()>0){ 'your foreach code here' }`

Comment: please check my answer it' helps you. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/229188/magento-2-get-order-list-items-for-a-customer/307904#307904

Comment: Please check my answer and update me.

Answer (score 1):

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Block**

**OrderList.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class OrderList extends Template
{
    protected $_orderCollectionFactory;
    protected $orderRepository;
    protected $_customerSession;

    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getLoggedinCustomerId() 
    {
        if ($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            return $this->_customerSession->getId();
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function getOrderList($cust_id)
    {
        $order_collection = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create();
        $order_collection->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $cust_id);
        $order_collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');

        return $order_collection;
    }

    public function getOrderCount($cust_id)
    {
        $order_collection = $this->getOrderList($cust_id);
        return count($order_collection->getData());
    }

    public function getOrderItems($order_id)
    {
        return $this->orderRepository->get($order_id);
    }
}
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/frontend/templates**

**orderlist.phtml**

```
//echo "<pre>";
$cust_id = $block->getLoggedinCustomerId();

$order_data = $block->getOrderList($cust_id);

//print_r($block->getOrderList($block->getLoggedinCustomerId())->getData()) ;

echo "<table border='1'><tr><th>Order ID</th><th>Order Items</th></tr>";
foreach ($order_data as $order_key => $order_value) {
    echo "<tr>";
    $order_id = $order_value->getIncrementId();
    echo "<td>".$order_id."</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    $order_items = $block->getOrderItems($order_id);
    if (!empty($order_items)) {
        foreach ($order_items->getAllVisibleItems() as $key_items => $value_items) {
            echo $value_items->getName()."<br/>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "No Items Found";
    }

    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

> You can add this to your layout where you want to show order items list.

```
<block class="VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\OrderList" name="customer_order_items" template="VendoreName_ModuleName::orderlist.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Comment: It looks like $block->getOrderItems($order_id); needs to send the entity id, rather than the order id to the function - I changed that and this then works well.

Comment: @Msquare how to get order count here of the logged in customer

Comment: @Pramod I added getOrderCount() function which return order count of particular customer.

Comment: this line :- return count($order_collection->getData()); in getOrderCount($cust_id) function throws error  which says ParseError: syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN)

Comment: @Pramod sorry it's a small mistake. I solve it now.

Comment: between what was the issue

Comment: @Pramod getOrderCount($cust_id) to $this->getOrderCount($cust_id) I miss $this variable.

Comment: @Msquare still getting this issue ParseError: syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN) in /app/code/vendor/module/Block/Success.php:47 Stack trace: #0 /vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(322)

Comment: @Pramod missing semicolon. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
public function getOrders($customerId)
{

    if (!$this->orders) {
       $this->orders = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()
    ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', [
        'eq' => $customerId
    ])
    ->setOrder('created_at', 'desc');
    }
    return $this->orders;
}
```

Comment: it displays an error on front-end : Invalid argument supplied for foreach().                 I  added  if(is_array($orders) || is_object($orders))  before the foreach but now it doesn't display sth new

Comment: So the problem is caused because i am passing something to foreach loop that is not an array