# Magento 2 Order history with configurable Product get product id and attributes

Tags: orders, sales-order

below is code to get product id from order id, I did order configurable product but in below case it show 2 product ids where as I did purchased only one product (configurable products).

output of below code is two id one is main products and other configurable made from that one, I want to verify get instead one id

```
$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->loadByIncrementId($_order->getRealOrderId());
                        $orderItems = $order->getAllItems();

                        foreach ($orderItems as $item) {
                            echo $item->getId();
                            echo "<br>";
                            echo "xxxx".$item->getProductId()."-->";

                         }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to change function . First know about function.

This is how the different methods to get items from an order work:

> **getItems():** returns array of items from loaded order item collection
>
> **getAllItems():** returns array of all items that are not marked as deleted
>
> **getAllVisibleItems():** returns array of all items that are not marked as deleted and do not have a parent item

```
$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->loadByIncrementId($_order->getRealOrderId());
                        $orderItems = $order->getAllVisibleItems();

                        foreach ($orderItems as $item) {
                            echo $item->getId();
                            echo "<br>";
                            echo "xxxx".$item->getProductId()."-->";

                         }
```

[Click here to show order items](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/229188/magento-2-get-order-list-items-for-a-customer/307904#307904)