# Magento2 - How to get dynamically Order number?

Tags: magento2

File Path :

`SR\DeliveryDate\view\adminhtml\templates\order_info_shipping_info.phtml`

code:

```
<section class="admin__page-section" id="delivery-date-content">
    <div class="admin__page-section-title">
        <span class="title"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Delivery Date Information')) ?></span>
    </div>
    <div class="admin__page-section-content">
        <div id="delivery-date">
            <strong><?= __('Delivery Date') ?></strong>
            <span><?= $block->getDeliveryDate() ?></span>
        </div>
        <div id="delivery-comment">
            <strong><?= __('Comment') ?>:</strong>
            <br/>
            <?= $block->getDeliveryComment() ?>
        </div>
        <div id="delivery-test">
            <strong><?= __('Test') ?>:</strong>
            <br/>
            <?php
                $orderid = 33;
                $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                $order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface')->load($orderid);

                //fetch whole order information
                //print_r($order->getData());

                //Or fetch specific information
                //echo $order->getIncrementId();
                //echo $order->getGrandTotal();
                //echo $order->getSubtotal();
                echo $order->getDeliveryDropdown();
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(
        ['jquery'],
        function($) {
            $('#delivery-date-content').insertAfter($('.order-view-billing-shipping'));
        }
    );
</script>
```

Line No : `$orderid = 33;`

I want get dynamically order number after place order.

Can anyone help create block and call to phtml file?

Comment: try this way https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/307904/82670

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this module get database values dynamically in admin panel edit some code this file :-

**SR/DeliveryDate/Observer/AddHtmlToOrderShippingView.php** and add this line in 64 number

```
$deliveryDateBlock->setDeliveryDropdown($order->getDeliveryDropdown());
```

Second open the this file **SR/DeliveryDate/Observer/AddHtmlToOrderShippingBlock.php**.And add this line

```
$deliveryDateBlock->setDeliveryDropdown($order->getDeliveryDropdown());
```

Final get values in template file

Go to template path :- **SR/DeliveryDate/view/adminhtml/templates/order_info_shipping_info.phtml**

add this

```
<div id="delivery-dropdown">
            <strong><?= __('Dropdown') ?>:</strong>
            <br/>
            <?= $block->getDeliveryDropdown(); ?>
        </div>
```

After check this output

Hope this help you

Thanks ...

Answer (score 1):

**app/code/SR/DeliveryDate/Block/Adminhtml**

**OrderList.php**

```
<?php

namespace SR\DeliveryDate\Block\Adminhtml;

class OrderList extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Template
{
    protected $_orderCollectionFactory;
    protected $orderRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getOrderList($cust_id)
    {
        $order_collection = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create();
        $order_collection->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $cust_id);
        $order_collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');

        return $order_collection;
    }
    public function getOrderItems($order_id)
    {
        return $this->orderRepository->get($order_id);
    }
}
```

**app/code/SR/DeliveryDate/view/adminhtml/templates**

**orderlist.phtml**

```
<section class="admin__page-section" id="delivery-date-content">
    <div class="admin__page-section-title">
        <span class="title"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Delivery Date Information')) ?></span>
    </div>
    <div class="admin__page-section-content">
        <div id="delivery-date">
            <strong><?= __('Delivery Date') ?></strong>
            <span><?= $block->getDeliveryDate() ?></span>
        </div>
        <div id="delivery-comment">
            <strong><?= __('Comment') ?>:</strong>
            <br/>
            <?= $block->getDeliveryComment() ?>
        </div>
        <div id="delivery-test">
            <strong><?= __('Test') ?>:</strong>
            <br/>
            <?php

                $cust_id = 1 // get your customer id here and assigne to this varible

                $order_data = $block->getOrderList($cust_id);

                //print_r($block->getOrderList($block->getLoggedinCustomerId())->getData()) ;


                // get all customer orders
                foreach ($order_data as $order_key => $order_value) {

                    // get order id
                    $order_id = $order_value->getIncrementId();

                    // get order data 
                    $order_items = $block->getOrderItems($order_id);

                    // print your data 
                    if (!empty($order_items)) {
                        echo $order_items->getIncrementId()." - ";
                        echo $order_items->getGrandTotal()." - ";
                        echo $order_items->getSubtotal()."<br/>";
                    } else {
                        echo "No Record Found";
                    }

                }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(
        ['jquery'],
        function($) {
            $('#delivery-date-content').insertAfter($('.order-view-billing-shipping'));
        }
    );
</script>
```

> You can add this to your layout where you want to show order items list.

```
<block class="SR\DeliveryDate\Block\Adminhtml\OrderList" name="customer_order_items" template="SR_DeliveryDate::orderlist.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
```

> Run Magento command

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d-f 
php bin/magento c:c
php bin/magento c:f
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Comment: I have question. Can we put code from: orderlist.phtml directly to ourt template order_info_shipping_info.phtml ? I put  this code directly to order_info_shipping_info.phtml but still something wrong.  Thanks for check

Comment: You should change file name in layout also.